# iOS App displayed with grey icon in Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Deploying my iOS application to Testflight results in a grey-ish app icon.

All the icons are PNG files saved without transparency. In XCode 9.0 everything looks fine: 
[image: Icons as seen in XCode]

In iTunes Connect the app icons seems to have the right color: 
[image: Icons as seen in iTunes Connect]

Yet Testflight displays a greyish version of the icon:
[image]

The app icon on the home screen looks fine too.

It's the first time I stumpled upon this issue. 
Did you encounter this problem? 
How did you solve it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the color space of the image?

Comment: The color space in Photoshop is sRGB IEC61966-2.1 - the icons are then exported as PNG without transparency. The color profile is not embedded in the exported files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We tried different color profiles, web tools, nothing worked. Then we added red and green numbers to our icons to find out which of the image files was used for the generation of the app icon in Testflight – and suddently the problem disappeared.

As strange as that sounds but **adding a magenta dot in the corner of the icon solved the problem**.

(The dot is not visible to the user since the corners are rounded)

Comment: I had same problem and I can confirm this works. It is strange, but I guess it is some bug that should be fixed by Apple.

Comment: Can confirm it works. Just added a 1px magenta dot on the top left corner, and now it's solved!
I guess that the color dot makes our Black/grey/white images look like full RGB Color, and so are processed in a different way. (Yes, my icon was also made with black/greys/white, no colors)

Comment: There's an Apple dev forum post about this problem and users there also report that adding a bit of colour to the icon is a workaround. _sigh_ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88065

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with a MacOS app. A magenta dot solved the problem but the dot is visible!

Comment: An invisible (0 alpha) colored dot solved the problem. This makes no sense because my icon is very colorful. The linked forum thread claims that this problem is due to icons being grayscale. This is stupid